# AngularJS multiple controller program flow

Tags: angularjs

I'm not that good with AgularJS I might be missing simple basics here. I have 2 controllers actually 3 on the same page, lets talk only about the other 2. My problems is; the program runs the 2rd controller 1st while I would like for it to run the 1st controller first as the 2rd controller depends on the customerId provided on the 1st controller.

Controller1 (with)-> Service A

Controller2 (with)-> Service B (and depends on)-> Service A

On Service A I have a variable customerId and data-ng-init in Controller1 assign the customerId. Then Controller2 data-ng-init get Customer Orders and therefore it needs customerId. Now controller2 can't get orders because customerId is empty. When I debug my code I find that Controller2 runs first then Controller1.

I'm not sure if this have anything to do with anything but, on the HTML page Controller1 appear first and even my script call Controller1 is the first one called. I even tried to put Controller2 inside Controller1 on HTML but no difference.

```
<div data-ng-controller="customerController" data-ng-init="getCustomer()">
</div>
<div data-ng-controller="cusomerOrdersController" data-ng-init="getCustomerOrders()">
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: How does getCustomer() work? I guess that it is asynchronously and getCustomerOrders() gets called before customer is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use `$broadcast` event to call method which called from `ng-init` directive, because `ng-init` directive will get called when html is compiling by angular, & there is no customerId available, because it is set using ajax call.

Basically you need to broadcast event after getting `customerId` and then listen that event and called desired function instead of calling it from `ng-init`

**controller A** (broadcast here after getting customerId)

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('EventBroadCasted', $scope.customerId)
```

**controller B** (listen broadcast event here)

```
$scope.$on('EventBroadCasted', function(event, data){
   //data parameter will contain customerId you can pass it to method
   $scope.getCustomerOrders(customerId); //call method here
});
```

Comment: Wow @pankajparkar that worked like a charm, you're a star. Thank you.